# My nextDouble(); scanner is giving me a "cannott find symbol" error

Tags: java, input

I am doing a project for my computer science class and I have run into an issue that wont let me proceed, I ma trying to do a really simple user input question but I keep getting an error. Here is my code and the error:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BeekeepingIncome{

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
   double rawHoney;
   double honeyCombs; 
   double rent = 534.99;
   
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   System.out.println("How much honey in pounds was purchased?");
   rawHoney = nextdouble();
   System.out.println("How many honey combs in pounds were purchased?");

   
   
   
   
   }
   
}

BeekeepingIncome.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
   rawHoney = nextDouble();
              ^
  symbol:   method nextDouble()
  location: class BeekeepingIncome
1 error
```

Any way I can fix this?

Comment: You need to invoke the `nextDouble()` method on the "scanner" object.

Comment: sorry but can you go more into detail? @camickr

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your `Scanner`:

```
rawHoney = scanner.nextDouble();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: @Tywill7, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer), so people know the problem has been solved.